# Flutter android build directory has multiple apks

Tags: android, flutter

When running flutter build apk I find two apks

one under apk folder and another under flutter-apk folder.

whats the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you run `flutter build apk` .
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
To generate an app bundle, run:

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
```

[Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

or simply

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood my bad!